# Font Embedding Issue

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an AS3 project. Which uses say 100 swfs, these are very small swf's from 5-15 kb a piece. All of these swf's have a textfield in them. I need to embed a font in those text fields.

- If I embed the font in every swf, that's going to bump up the size a lot .
- I cannot break apart the text as it's dynamic.
- Text formatting is different in different swf's

Taking those points into consideration, what would be the best way to embed a font and how ?

Comment: check this out about embeding fonts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735556/alternative-to-embedding-a-font-in-as3/6735870#6735870

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html

Did u try this way?

Comment: That looks good, can I keep my text formatting in the swf and just not keep the font?

Answer (score 0):

you could use "runtime shared libraries" - here is a nice tutorial on how they work:

http://old-wp.slekx.com/2010/01/flash-cs4-runtime-shared-library-tutorial/