# Text goes invisible on embeddedFont = true

Tags: actionscript-3

I register my fonts once they are loaded. In my head I should be able to use them once they are. But I wasn't so I tweaked my code, here it is but it still makes the text invisible. As soon as I do embedFonts = false, it starts working again.

```
        trace(Font.enumerateFonts()); // Returns an array and does show my Fonts embedded.


        var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
        var fontClass:Class = _model.getFont("HappyHell"); // Does return the Class
        var myFont:Font = new fontClass(); // Works
        format.font = myFont.fontName;
        format.size = 15;
        format.letterSpacing = 0.8;

        var test:TextField = new TextField();
        test.embedFonts = true;
        test.defaultTextFormat = format;

        test.text = "TESTING everything 13216";
        test.x = 30;
        test.y = 30;
        addChild(test);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `embededFonts = true` property then you need to have the font in your library.

Links:

- [Embedding fonts](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html)
- [Alternative embeding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735556/alternative-to-embedding-a-font-in-as3/6735870)

**UPDATE**

What does `trace ( myFont.fontName )` output?

try:

```
var myFont:Font = new HappyHell();
```

or

```
var myFont:Font = new fontClass() as Font;
```

Comment: The output is : "Happy Hell" 

The output of Font.enumerateFonts is [HappyHell][Joint][...] and Font.enumerateFonts()[0].fontName results in "Happy Hell"

Comment: I got it working, I had an swc embedded in the project. This SWC had a textfield using the font. Somehow flash doesn't appreciate that.