# Need to load fonts dynamically without embedding the font in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on a project where we are using Flash to load the images, while user viewing the images we are showing the tile label for the images. These title labels uses various fonts like comic sans, Georgia, verdana and more. By default the labels are shown in the Arial font. We need to make the font to load Dynamically based on the font selected by the user. The font should be used dynamically without embedding

we dont want to use by css.

Please help me out and to find the solution

Thanks in Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [StackTrace in Flash / ActionScript 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149073/stacktrace-in-flash-actionscript-3-0)

Answer (score 2):

Has google stopped working?

One of the very first results: http://www.leebrimelow.com/?p=807

Answer (score 0):

seriously you need to learn so search for stuff... When you creating a question there are dozens of similar question poped out for ya.

[Alternative to embedding a font in as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735556/alternative-to-embedding-a-font-in-as3/6735870#6735870)